# Is my robots.txt file correct to apply for Google AdSense?

Tags: adsense

I had applied for Google AdSense for 3 times and for every time, I'm getting the below response from Google:-

**We did not approve your application for the reasons listed below
Unable to review your site: While reviewing http://www.acloudtiger.com, we found that your site was down or unavailable. If you applied through an AdSense host partner, such as YouTube or Blogger, your hosted site was not available or not found (removed) at the time of the review.**

Following is my robots.txt :-

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

Sitemap: https://acloudtiger.com/sitemap_index.xml
```

Please assist to check and advise on this as I do not want another rejection from them before I correct the things at my end.